# How can I set Windows 10 timezone to Tunis?

Tags: windows-10, time-zone, regional-settings

How do I set up Windows 10 to be in the correct timezone for Tunis, Tunisia?

If I go to Settings, Time & Language, Date & Time, I can choose a timezone, but Tunis is not in the list. Why not? Other operating systems get this right. How do I fix this?

(I don't want to set the timezone to another one with a similar time offset, because I want the time to be adjusted automatically with daylight saving correctly.)

Answer (score 1):

The correct time zone for Tunisia in Windows is labeled as `(UTC+01:00) West Central Africa`.

You can either manually set your time zone like this:

[image: screenshot]

Or, you can turn on "Set time zone automatically" - which in most cases will correctly identify your time zone.

The reason it doesn't have a separate entry is because [Tunisia does not have daylight saving time](http://www.timeanddate.com/time/change/tunisia/tunis), and there are multiple other African countries that also use this time zone.  It is not distinct enough, in terms of UTC offset and recent transition history, to warrant its own time zone entry.

Comment: Interesting.. Both on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tunisia) and at http://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/tunisia/tunis the timezone is listed as CET (also UTC+1:00) - an interesting discussion can be found here: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_vista-networking/vista-has-the-gmt1-west-central-africa-time-zone/7dcefde3-aa56-e011-8dfc-68b599b31bf5

Comment: The zone applies to 13 different countries in Africa.  Only Algeria and Tunisia call it "CET" while the other 11 call it "WAT" ([West Africa Time](http://www.timeanddate.com/time/zones/wat)).  The description in Windows is not intended to align with either name, but simply to identify the region where the zone is applicable.

Comment: hi, do you know of a source that could help me pick a correct timezone from windows list, mine is not listed but I know I´m in an offset of -04:00 from UTC. The problem is there are like 7 regions with the same offset, I was hoping to pick the nearest to mine (or do you think I can pick any and won´t make a difference) thanks. ps: **Set time zone automatically** not working for me

Comment: @J.M.Echevarría - By your profile, it looks like you are in Cuba.  Your time zone should be `(UTC-05:00) Havana`.  Leave the "adjust for daylight saving time automatically" on, and it will correctly chose UTC-4 during DST and UTC-5 during standard time.  If you don't see that time zone in the list, then you need to run a Windows Update.

Comment: thanx, that is working, only I had this itch in my brain (sure u know) because according to everything I have read, my city is -04:00 and, yes, my capital, Havana, is -05:00, so I was wondering *shouldn't -04:00 be the one working?*, while in reality *some* -4 and *some* -5 work as well, anyway thank you very much

Comment: The offsets in the list are the ones in effect *during standard time* - not the ones *currently* in effect.  Common source of confusion - but if you think about it, the list would have to constantly be rearranged it they were to be the current offsets.

Comment: As far as why to pick Havana, consider that Cuba's DST change dates are the same as the US Eastern time zone, but the US transitions occur at 2:00 AM, while Cuba's occur at Midnight or 1:00 AM.  See https://www.timeanddate.com/time/change/cuba/havana  vs https://www.timeanddate.com/time/change/usa/new-york